# １ヶ月内で、週ごとの処理を実行する方法を教えてください。

Tags: php

例えば11月の場合

```
start = '2022-11-01'
end   = '2022-11-30'

saturdayList = 
Array
(
[0] => 2022-11-05
[1] => 2022-11-12
[2] => 2022-11-19
[3] => 2022-11-26
)
```

１ヶ月内で週ごとに特定の処理を行うループを作りたいのですがうまくいきません。
１週間ごとに `$weekDayArray` を割り当てる処理を行いたいです。

```
//result
 array (
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'tue',
    1 => 22,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'wed',
    1 => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'fri',
    1 => 44,
  ),
```

```
$weekDayArray =
array("sun"=>"1", "mon"=>22 "tue"=>33 "wed"=>32 "thu"=>44 "fri"=>34 "sat"=>44);
//*$weekDayArrayは週ごとにランダムに変わる。日曜・土曜・祝日設定により入らない場合、
//e.g. array( "mon"=>22 "tue"=>33 "wed"=>32 "thu"=>44 "fri"=>99); 可変
            for($i = $start_date,$k=0;  $i <= $end_date ;)
            {
                if($saturdayList[$k])
                {
                    
                }
                    for($j = $i ; $j <= $end_date  &&(int)date_create($j)->format('w')< 7 ; $j++)
                    {}
$k++
}
```

割り当てる関数

```
private function assignWeekRange($dailyCompositionArray,$weeklyStapleFoodRatioArray,$start_date,$end_date)
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach($dailyCompositionArray as $key => $day){
         if($key >= date_create($start_date)->format('j') && $key <= date_create($end_date)->format('j') )
         {
            
         
          if(isset($weeklyStapleFoodRatioArray[$day])){
            $result[$key] = [$day,$weeklyStapleFoodRatioArray[$day]];
          } else {
            $result[$key] = [$day,null];
          }
        }
        }
        return $result;

    }
```

for($i = $start_date,$k=0;  $i <= $end_date ;)以下で

```
      print_r(date_create($i)->format('w') );
```

を実行した時に、2345とだけ出力されます・・・
謎です。

Comment: ソースコードを貼る際は [Markdown の強調表示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) を使うと見やすく表示されるので、次回から試してみてください。

Comment: 参考: [Get week number in month from date in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32615861)